# Statistics terminology: Is there a word for a flat bottom?

Tags: single-word-requests, statistics

I'm wondering about the opposite of a plateau. I mean, I tend to associate "valley" with a downward spike, as in peaks and valleys. I want to talk of "a flat bottom on the data graph" in the same way that you might talk about a plateau in the graph.

Comment: A flat bottom? Call it "Bane of SirMixalot".

Comment: What is the opposite of ocean ? How is this related to stats ? You mean some geographical term for uneven lowland? As according to wiki, plateau is  "flat high plain". Why don't  you try cross-validated ?

Comment: If there is no oft-used term, I would like to submit [**morass**](https://www.google.com/search?q=morass). It has both the physical landscape similarity (low-lying, flat) and the connotation that finding it on a chart yields (stagnant, encumbered, unable to grow/change).

Comment: @Argot I suppose I didn't establish the connection; this is related to stats because I want to talk of "a flat bottom on the data graph" in the same way that you might talk about a plateau in the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Trough*** might work. It is the low point between peaks or waves.

> [A long, narrow depression between waves or ridges; the low portion of a wave cycle.](https://www.wordnik.com/words/trough)

It also has an [economic definition.](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/trough.asp)

> In general, the business cycle is said to go through expansion, then the peak, followed by contraction, and then it finally bottoms out with the trough.

Answer (score 0):

Consider "[bowl](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bowl):"

> bowl: a bowl-shaped depression of the land surface.

E.g.

[It reshapes the q-field, creating "bowls" and "plateaus" which allow the flow to cross latitude circles.](http://www.ocean.washington.edu/courses/oc513spr10/rhines-mcdowell-PV-JPO82.pdf)

[There are numerous bowls and plateaus.](http://golfclubatlas.com/forum/index.php?topic=38492.0;wap2)

> A flat-bottomed bowl (or basin) is a [pan](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pan).
>
> pan (also called "[playa](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/playa)" or "dry lake"): flat-bottomed depression that is periodically covered by water.

E.g.

[Located at the southern end of the Great Rift Valley, the4,000 sq. km. park has diverse ecosystems including savannah, rain-filled pans and plateaus with miombo...](http://www.aardvarksafaris.co.uk/mozambique/central-mozambique#.U0RFrIcayK0)

Comment: Bowls aren't flat! What kind of gourmet are you?? ;)

Comment: @DigitalChris Well, at least it can be considered as the opposite of a plateau. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If I were describing a flat on the graph that was down near the axis, I would call it a *low plateau*.  A plateau doesn't necessarily imply height beyond being above baseline.

If it on the baseline, I would call it either a baseline plateau, or even just name the axis of the graph itself.  (The x-axis, etc.)

If it is a true low-point, you can use the term [**nadir**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nadir).

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is just valley.  When I think of a valley I think of something that goes down, is then pretty flat, and goes back up.  If that is what your graph does I would go with valley.  If it is sharper then you could use gorge or canyon.

Other graph phrases:

- stagnant dip
- dip then flat line

If you don't think valleys are flat you could go with inverted plateau.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're coming at this from the perspective of statistics, why not the mathematical concept of "asymptote"?

Comment: Please consider adding to your answer a definition of _asymptote_ from a reliable source. That way, the answer will be more complete and self-contained—and more helpful to readers who may not grasp at once why _asymptote_ might be a suitable suggestion. Thanks!